# How to hide antd Modal header

Tags: reactjs, antd

my question is how to hide ant modal header

[image]

how to remove my modal section ?
the simple code is :

```
export default React.memo(() => {
 return <Modal
        width={800} 
        footer={<div/>} 
       >
       
       </Modal>
 });
```

i try to put header in property but not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The header text can be changed via the [`title`](https://ant.design/components/modal/#API) prop. If you don't want a title at all, you can pass an empty string.

```
export default React.memo(() => {
  return (
    <Modal
      title=""
      width={800}
      footer={<div />}
    >
    </Modal>
  );
});
```

Comment: that's not remove the section but just title

Comment: Which section exactly are you trying to remove then? The header's part at the top with the bottom border is removed for me when the title is empty: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-mclean-h5p79

Comment: Perhaps you need to add some content in the modal to see the difference.

Answer (score 3):

As of right now it seems you can get rid of the top part by just not supplying a value to the "title" prop.